# HighStock Print Setting To Hide Range Selector

Tags: highcharts

Using HighStock we want to give the user the option to print but we want to remove the `rangeSelector` from the image when we export. The following code does this for exporting to a file but it appears to be ignored when using print:

```
exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    buttons: {
        enabled: false
    },
    filename: 'UnempRate',
    width: 590
}
```

Note that we have the export buttons disabled because we are calling from a different HTML element. Even if we use the built-in buttons it will still show the `rangeSelector` on print.

This is related to my other question on the navigator series and chart title issues on export: [HighStock Export Renders Incorrect Title and Navigator Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549641/highstock-export-renders-incorrect-title-and-navigator-series)

Answer (score 1):

Please take look at this example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/4ZMNg/
```

which export image without rangeselector:

```
 exporting:{
            chartOptions:{
                rangeSelector:{
                    enabled:false
                }
            }

        },
```

Comment: This works when exporting to image. This does not work when using the print export method. My question states this does work for image export. My question is why does this not work for print export.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Crystall/jyfs8/).

It was difficult, but I've finally got it. If you also need to hide `exporting` buttons, try to achieve it by yourself.

Comment: This looks pretty heavy handed. Will give it a shot and let you know. We do not have to worry about the export buttons as we use an HTML element outside the chart to trigger the export/print.

Comment: Okay. tested this out on our site and it actually does not print but it does cause the chart to "un-render" after clicking on print. It gives error that `this.rangeSelector.inputGroup[whatToDo]();`is undefined. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/rSdPW/3/. Does this only work under v3/1.3 that was released today?

Comment: No, on the contrary - it only works with the previous version. I'll fix it to work on both, if you need.